# Connecting my Windows Phone's GPS as a Windows Location Sensor

Tags: windows-8, location, windows-phone

I came across a piece of software about a year ago which would emulate a windows location sensor so that a legacy GPS device that connects over a serial connection (via bluetooth) and windows would recognise the coordinates as valid. I have upgraded to windows 8 since then, but the location it has is still the cached result from that test all that time ago.

In the last week, I have been thinking of a piece of software (a mobile app and a desktop application) that will parse the data from one to the other.

I have built the mobile app, and it successfully parses the gps coordinates to the desktop app, now the last bit (the trickiest bit) is to attempt to install a gps sensor daemon into the system that will parse these coordinates to windows (so all my apps will be perfectly synced with my current location). I have looked on google, but can't find many helping pointers. I am hoping to be able to do this in `C#.net`, but if it can only be done in `C++`, thats cool. Any resources that could help me with this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463473.aspx

One of the examples deals with creating a Win8 device driver for a GPS.  I haven't done this myself, though.